# Programmatic cache

Tags: c#, caching

What does follwoing code lines will do.

This will set the cache time.

```
Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(60));
```

What does this do?

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
```

What does this do?.. first line of code set cache then why this line of code needs true ?

```
Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);
```

Thanks in advance
Divya

Answer (score 1):

`Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);`

"Sets the Cache-Control HTTP header. The Cache-Control HTTP header controls how documents are to be cached on the network." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setcacheability(v=VS.100).aspx

--

`Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(true);`

"Specifies whether the ASP.NET cache should ignore HTTP Cache-Control headers sent by the client that invalidate the cache." - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcachepolicy.setvaliduntilexpires.aspx

Answer (score 0):

HttpCacheability.NoCache sets the response header to no-cache as described here..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c4yy9w70.aspx